# Can I use more than one sectionNameKeyPath in a fetchedResultsController?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a list of 'bills' in core data.
For each bill I want there to be a separate section in a UITableViewController.
I want these bills to be sorted by amount.

To do this I use a fetchedResultsController.
Each bill has an amount and billID.
I have made the sortDescriptor 'amount' and the sectionNameKeyPath 'billID'. This causes problems because didChangeSection does not get called appropriately when it needs to.

I did some digging and came across this post: [Custom Section Name Crashing NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475542/custom-section-name-crashing-nsfetchedresultscontroller)

And it looks like the Apple documentation says the primary sort descriptor needs to be the same as the sectionNameKeyPath.

I have kept the sortDescriptor as 'amount' and changed the sectionNameKeyPath as 'billID'. This has fixed the behavior. However, if two bills have the same 'amount' they will be in the same section, which I don't want. Is there anyway I can have the sectionNameKeyPath depend on two variables, for example, 'amount', and 'billID' so I can guarantee a separate section for each bill, yet have it sorted by amount?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The `sortDescriptor` property of `NSFetchRequest` is actually an array. We are able to pass more than one `sortDescriptor` to it based on the order of the properties to want the results to be sorted.

Try this ordering `sortDecriptor`s

```
request.sortDescriptors= @[billIdSortDescriptor, amountSortDescriptor];
```

Here, the `request` is the `NSFetchRequest` passed to the `NSFetchedResultsController`
So the results will be first sorted by bill id and objects with same `billID` will be sorted by amount.